# Why did Saudi prince visit Israel?

Tags: israel, middle-east, saudi-arabia

There have been reports of Saudi Crown Prince bin Salman [going on a secret visit to Israel](https://twitter.com/NTarnopolsky/status/906928824931307520). What can be the reasons behind it?

Comment: Asking about the reasons for a secret visit which may or may not have taken place seems speculative. I'm voting to close for now.

Comment: Answers have closed down else I would have posted this as one: it is historically not unheard of for neighboring rulers to make secret visits to Israel for various discussions.  They are all neighbors, after all, and do see the need to discuss issues from time to time.  King Hussein of Jordan was known to make helicopter visits at night.  Source: Rabinovich's "The Yom Kippur War." That a Saudi visited Israel itself might be unprecedented, but I would be surprised if they have not had secret meetings at 3rd party locations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several things Saudi Arabia may want to discuss with Israel. The two countries have no diplomatic relations, but are not extremely hostile toward each other. Talks between their leaders are sensitive, but not unthinkable.

Some things they may discuss:

- Iran - both countries are worried about Iran's growing influence in the Middle East, as well as its nuclear ambitions, and may discuss possible actions.
- Palestine -  Saudi Arabia has proposed the [Arab Peace Initiative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arab_Peace_Initiative) and may want to convince Israel to discuss it.
- Syria - the interests of both Saudi Arabia and Israel in Syria are complicated. There may be issues where both have common interests worth discussing.

Comment: Minor nitpick: Israel's interest in Syria isn't that complicated (and KSA's is even simpler). Israel wishes to avoid strengthening of Shiite axis and improving Hezbollah's military position (tactically or materially) on one hand; and secondarily, avoid having a lawless country or ISIStan in replacement of Alwaite regime on the other hand. And yes, these are somewhat hard to reconcile and balance. KSA just wants to slap down Iran and shiite axis in general. Good answer otherwise though some sourcing would improve it.